# Backbone.js collection comparator not sorting by number

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I have a backbone collection called `users`, with each `user` having a unique `name` and non-unique `page`.  I would like to sort this `users` collection by page, but Backbone's `comparator` is giving the same results as when no `comparator` is declared.

Let's say I have a collection of users like so (added one by one, from top to bottom):

```
name: B, page: 1
name: D, page: 2
name: A, page: 3
name: C, page: 4
```

If I do

```
class Entities.Users extends Backbone.Collection
  ...
  comparator: (u) ->
    u.get("name").toUpperCase()
```

Then the sorting is as expected (by `name`):

```
name: A, page: 3
name: B, page: 1
name: C, page: 4
name: D, page: 2
```

However, if I try sorting by `page`:

```
comparator: (u) ->
  parseInt u.get("page")
```

Then the collection does not sort properly (page 1 is always at the end):

```
name: D, page: 2
name: A, page: 3
name: C, page: 4
name: B, page: 1
```

Why does this happen, and how can I sort properly by `page`?

**EDIT**

This also doesn't work with the plain string version of `page`:

```
comparator: (u) ->
  u.get("page")
```

Comment: could marionette be applying some sort of filter in the view or something? (sorry not so familiar with marionette)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, it looks like the collection was actually sorting, it just wasn't doing a full re-render after each new `fetch({remove: false})`.  I added a listener to the CompositeView like so:

```
class MyClass extends Marionette.CompositeView
  ...
  initialize: ->
    @collection.on "sync", () => @render()
```

And it is obeying the comparator as expected now.  I still have no idea why this was **not** also a problem when sorting by `name` though.

Comment: did you add the models by name in sequential order?

Comment: No, and as a matter of fact they are being added by `page` in sequential order!

Comment: interesting... sounds like something might be happening behind the scenes then

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried only this :

```
comparator: "page"
```

Comment: I have, unfortunately it doesn't change anything